# puppetlabbs/firewall on centos 7.2

Tags: centos, puppet

I'm trying to do this (with Puppet CE 4.3.2 and the puppetlabs/firewall modules from the forge):

```
 firewall { '110 allow http/https access':
    dport  => [80, 443],
    proto  => tcp,
    action => accept,
  }
```

When I try to apply this on CentOS 7.2 I get

```
Warning: Firewall[110 allow http/https access](provider=iptables): Unable to persist firewall rules: Execution of '/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init save' returned 1:
```

I looked through the bugreports but could only find resolved bugs but it is still not working for me. Anyone who has had any luck with this?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The proposed workaround is to install iptables:

```
 package { 'iptables-services':
    ensure  => installed,
 }
```

The ticket is closed however is still affects Centos 7.2 https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-1029